# Can i use license plate recognition dll in webbrowser MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a website for my organization (license plate recognition).my organization right now uses a system that i think it can be more better .

**The current application :**

In current application there is a windows form that gets the video stream from IP camera and detects the plate and sends the plate character (string) to my website (By using API Service MVC).

So i want to remove the application (windows form that detects the plate) and embed the application inside the webbrowser i mean i want to remove my windows form application .when my users open the website ,the browser gets the camera stream and uses the local DLL to detect the plate  (I want to detect the plate inside user pc not my server) and submit the plate string character in the website .

My question is :is it possible to detect the plate string without application just in browser .

If Yes :Could you give me more details ?

Comment: I don't think so, you only have minimal access to the client pc for obvious security reasons. What you can do is accessing the client's camera, send those streams to your server, handle it there. But handling on the client with a. NET application is not possible if the user won't install the application.

Answer (score 0):

One popular way is using the jQuery web cam plugin as demonstrated here:
 https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Capture-Image-Photo-from-Web-Camera-Webcam-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">    
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0"cellspacing="0">    
        <tr>    
            <td align="center">    
                <u>Live Camera</u>    
            </td>    
            <td>    
            </td>    
            <td align="center">    
                <u>Captured Picture</u>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="webcam">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Image ID="imgCapture" runat="server" Style="visibility: hidden;
                    width: 320px; height: 240px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <br />

    <asp:Button ID="btnCapture" Text="Capture"runat="server" OnClientClick="return Capture();"/>

    <br />

    <span id="camStatus"></span>
</form>
```

C#

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Services;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.InputStream.Length > 0)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
            {
                string hexString = Server.UrlEncode(reader.ReadToEnd());
                string imageName = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy hh-mm-ss");
                string imagePath = string.Format("~/Captures/{0}.png", imageName);

                File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath(imagePath), ConvertHexToBytes(hexString));

                Session["CapturedImage"] = ResolveUrl(imagePath);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static byte[] ConvertHexToBytes(string hex)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[hex.Length / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i += 2)
    {
        bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    }

    return bytes;
}

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string GetCapturedImage()
{
    string url = HttpContext.Current.Session["CapturedImage"].ToString();

    HttpContext.Current.Session["CapturedImage"] = null;

    return url;
}
```

You could change this to work with MVC relatively easily. Here is a great example: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/capturing-image-from-web-cam-in-Asp-Net-mvc139/.